# How to configure 'uiGmapgoogle-maps' API key after bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs

So, I am using uiGmapgoogle-maps in my angular project. I need to specify the API key, According to their documentation is needs to be done in the bootstrap process as a config:

```
.config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        key: 'your api key',
        v: '3.20', //defaults to latest 3.X anyhow
        libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
    });
})
```

However, my issue is I don't have the API until later on in the applications life. To be specific, the api key is in the database and is specific to a user. The user would need to login and then we can access the api key.

I did some research into lazy loading angularjs controllers but I couldn't get my head around how to sort this specific issue.

So, how would I run this configuration after the boostrap process? Specifically from a controller.

Comment: Why does each user have his own API key? is it a requirement?

Comment: Separately. I think that the version needs to be at least 3.22 to work --- I used the same library in a project a short time ago...I can't find the reference on Google Map API but it definitely needed changing

Comment: @MuliYulzary yes this is a requirement of the application.

Comment: @mjabraham I am running version of 'uiGmapgoogle-maps'. How does the version of Google map API affect angular configuration? I am not sure I follow.

Comment: Iv sorted the issue, and posted my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question after fixing this issue.

I created a provider:

```
provider('GmapsKey', class GmapsKey {
    constructor() {
        this.uiGmaps = null;
    }

    set key(key) {
        this.uiGmaps.configure({key});
    }

    $get() {
        return this;
    }
});
```

and

```
config(['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', 'GmapsKeyProvider', (uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider, GmapsKeyProvider) => {
    GmapsKeyProvider.uiGmaps = uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider;
}]);
```

Once I had my key ready, I injected `GmapsKey` and set the key:

```
   GmapsKey.key = userConfig.uGMapAPIKey;
```