# AngularJS: Injecting rootScope or service variable in config

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, rootscope

I get data from the DB and want to set inside config. Now, I get it inside $http.get in a service and store in a rootScope variable as well. How can I access inside config? I saw some examples, do I need a Provider? Any simple example will help a lot. Thanks!

PS. I m configuring api key for google maps

Update: I have a provider like the following, and I get the API key value in Run and set it in rootScope. Where should I call setKey method?

```
    function GmapsKeyProvider() {
    var _key = null;
    this.setKey = function(key){
        _key = key;
    };
    this.$get = function (){
      return _key;
    };
}
```

Comment: it's best to explain what data you are storing and where it is used. For example, if you need a **resolve** injection (per route), then you don't inject it into your config directly, but into the resolve function instead.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I want to specify APIkeys to google maps

Comment: you should try using their module - [angular-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/). You would need to inject `uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider` into your config and set it up with `uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({ key: 'YOUR_API_KEY', ... });`

Comment: Yes the key is from the backend. I m unable to do a $http.get inside config, please let me know how it can be done.

Comment: you can't really have a dynamic key, but you try to _hack_ it with `uiGmapMapScriptLoader` in some custom service that you can inject later. E.g. `uiGmapMapScriptLoader.load(options_with_api_key)`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey could you help with my updated question?

Comment: I suggest you read about [how to inject environmental variables](https://medium.com/@kudresov/a-better-way-to-inject-environmental-variables-in-angular-d3b2d01a3c5e) (such as API keys, etc.). But I just know that config is not for dynamic / async values.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I also saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854271/how-to-configure-uigmapgoogle-maps-api-key-after-bootstrap. But did not understand where the Provider was injected and how the setKey method was called

Comment: Provider is the same as a Service or Factory, just written differently. It's purpose is usually storage, and it can be injected anywhere else. In that example it was injected into the config and populated with `uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider` itself

Comment: Can I use a similar approach? I get api_key in Run(), but unable to inject Provider there and call the setKey() method.